# Wordpress plug-in - Tooltips not working

Tags: css, wordpress, tooltip, formcraft

I'm a design intern at Brickbacker, and we have a problem with our website:
http://brickbacker.com/

I'll try to make this short, but it isn't easy!

I've been given the task to fix a problem with tooltips not working correctly in a modal-pop-up, we made with the plug-in "Formcraft". It is activated when the button "Get started" is clicked.

When the tooltips are activated, they quickly appear at the wrong spot, and then become hidden.

We've tried to contact the developers of the plug-in as well as our theme, and they both say it might be a conflict with the theme or other plug-ins. We have tried to disable every plug-in one at a time while checking the tooltips - and it still doesn't work. We also tried to change the theme, but then the get-started button won't be shown.

I'm pretty sure it must be some kind of conflict between our theme Flatsome and Formcraft, but I absolutely can't tell whether it's in the CSS or somewhere else?

For some reason, whenever a tooltip is activated, the < div >-tag is still there. So if you hover over a tooltip 100 times, there will be 100 invisible < div >-tags. It's very strange.

So I was wondering if anyone is able to see what might be causing the problem, or have any tips as to how we can figure out where the conflict is?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try another tooltip plugin? There are plenty of them at [Wordpress Plugin Directory](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=tooltip). It would be much more complicated to find a conflict inside theme and plugin code than trying new plugins.

Comment: The problem is that Formcraft allows us to make the exact kind of pop-up we visually want, with functionalities we haven't really found in other plugins. The tooltips are a small part of the plugin, and they're the only thing not working as they should right now. Maybe we could find a plug-in with working tooltips that could work together with formcraft?

Comment: Yes you could use Formcraft for your visualization, except for tooltips, and look for a lighter, more tooltip-focused plugin for the tooltips only.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to look for something we can use, thank you for your help! :) I hope it's okay if I still keep the post open, if someone else knows how we might fix the problem with formcrafts tooltips.